# Reference Values in different columns

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

This question is best asked via example. I have the following data frame in R:

```
  date  SPX.Index.1stM.100..MnySPXindexprice day    c
1   2005-01-03  12.00050    1202.084    Monday          1202.084
2   2005-01-04  11.90630    1188.045    Tuesday         1188.045
3   2005-01-05  12.03420    1183.737    Wednesday   1183.737
4   2005-01-06  11.52000    1187.885    Thursday    1187.885
5   2005-01-07  11.15550    1186.193    Friday          1190.000
6   2005-01-08  11.08770    1190.245    Saturday    1190.245
7   2005-01-09  11.08770    1190.245    Sunday      1190.245
8   2005-01-10  11.08770    1190.245    Monday          1190.245
```

If the day is "Friday" I'd like to return the SPXindexprice VALUE of MONDAY in the same 'slot' as Friday. So in the example above, in line 5, I'd have a new column with value 1202.084 (MONDAY in day column) Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Do you mean the R programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in Python:

```
df = open("dataframe.txt").read()
splitData = df.split("\n")
out = open("output.txt", "w")

for row in splitData:
  splitRow = row.split()
  if len(splitRow) >= 4:
    if splitRow[4] == "Monday":
      mondayValue = splitRow[3]

      out.write(str(splitRow[0]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[1]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[2]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[3]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[4]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[5]) + "\n")

    elif splitRow[4] == "Friday":
      out.write(str(splitRow[0]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[1]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[2]) + "\t"
      + str(mondayValue) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[4]) + "\t"
      + str(mondayValue) + "\n")

    else:
      out.write(str(splitRow[0]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[1]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[2]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[3]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[4]) + "\t"
      + str(splitRow[5]) + "\n")
```

The output is tab separated:

```
row date    SPX.Index   1stM.100    MnySPXindexprice    day
1   2005-01-03  12.0005 1202.084    Monday  1202.084
2   2005-01-04  11.9063 1188.045    Tuesday 1188.045
3   2005-01-05  12.0342 1183.737    Wednesday   1183.737
4   2005-01-06  11.52   1187.885    Thursday    1187.885
5   2005-01-07  11.1555 1202.084    Friday  1202.084
6   2005-01-08  11.0877 1190.245    Saturday    1190.245
7   2005-01-09  11.0877 1190.245    Sunday  1190.245
8   2005-01-10  11.0877 1190.245    Monday  1190.245
```

Comment: Really appreciate it but is it possible to provide a solution in R? Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: I can, but I'm slow in R. You'll get an answer more quickly if you edit the title of your question to something like "If Condition in R" and tag the question with things like "dataframe" "R" etc.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I've changed the title. This has been an issue for me even in excel. I had to do a lot of the calculation manually!

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is sorted by date, then you could try this:

```
#reproducible dataframe
df <- read.table(text="date  SPX.Index MnySPXindexprice day    c
                 2005-01-03  12.00050    1202.084    Monday          1202.084
                 2005-01-04  11.90630    1188.045    Tuesday         1188.045
                 2005-01-05  12.03420    1183.737    Wednesday   1183.737
                 2005-01-06  11.52000    1187.885    Thursday    1187.885
                 2005-01-07  11.15550    1186.193    Friday          1190.000
                 2005-01-08  11.08770    1190.245    Saturday    1190.245
                 2005-01-09  11.08770    1190.245    Sunday      1190.245
                 2005-01-10  11.08770    1190.245    Monday          1190.245",
                 header=TRUE)

#assign monday row
df$MondayValue <- 
  ifelse(df$day!="Friday", NA,
         df[as.numeric(rownames(df[ df$day=="Friday",]))-4,"MnySPXindexprice"])
```

Comment: I think this works. It creates a new data.frame with values for each Monday. But how do I place it back into the original data.frame in the right spot? I.e. place new Monday value next to the value for Friday? And also only one column from the new data.frame, column "c"